# Instantiating certain objects (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I'm working with the [newsynth](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/newsynth) package and in particular would like to use the method [`gridsynth`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/newsynth-0.4.0.0/docs/Quantum-Synthesis-GridSynth.html#v:gridsynth), and my question is about how to instantiate the necessary objects to run it. I'm confused by the type `RandomGen g => g -> Double -> SymReal -> Int -> U2 DOmega` as the example on [the homepage](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/%7Eselinger/newsynth/) seems to only require a real number (e.g. `pi/128`) as input. Indeed, when I imported all necessary packages and tried

```
 λ> g <- getStdGen
 λ> gridsynth g pi/128 (Const 33) 25
```

I got back a trivial matrix. `pi/128` was chosen because it is the sample value, `Const 33` was chosen because I want epsilon to be about 10^10 ≈ 2^33, and `25` was chosen because the documentation suggests it, but the output is still trivial regardless of input. Any help demystifying this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’m not sure, but it looks like you’re somehow depending on two different incompatible versions of the `random` package. This error is saying that there’s no instance for the `RandomGen` typeclass from version 1.1 for the `StdGen` type from the *other* version, which you’re getting by using `import System.Random`. How are you running this? You should probably be using a Stack or Cabal project to fetch & build the right packages for you.

Comment: I'm currently just trying to get the hang of the package using the GHCi command line. My longer files (which aren't particularly long) I've just been running as .hs files thru GHCi (not using Stack or Cabal, I have Cabal installed but don't know how to use it other than for getting new packages, e.g. `cabal install ...`). Is it useful information to know what's in my .ghci file? I have `:set -package random` in there. Could that be causing issues? I don't know how else I could have two different `random`s going on...

Comment: You can use `ghc-pkg` to view and modify which package versions get selected for a given package name, and to see dependency tree information. I recommend using `ghc-pkg describe newsynth` to find out which version of `random` it depends on, then `ghc-pkg list random` to see which versions are exposed (normal font for exposed, colored font for hidden). If they don't match, you can use `ghc-pkg hide` and `ghc-pkg expose` to fix that up, then try again. (Not writing this as an answer because it doesn't address the other parts of your question.)

Comment: @DanielWagner thank you for this advice. Should I be able to run these commands from anywhere? `ghc-pkg describe newsynth` returns `ghc-pkg: cannot find package newsynth`, and `ghc-pkg list random` returns `~/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/package.conf.d   (no packages)`. (I then navigated to `~/.ghcup/ghc` and found only the one version of GHC, so it doesn't seem like there's multiple installations of that competing.)

Comment: Okay. That information leaves me a bit confused. How do you start ghci?

Comment: @DanielWagner As in what steps do I take to get into ghci / what's in my .gchi file, or how did I initially get ghci on my computer?

Comment: For the former, I just run it through Terminal command line, and my .ghci file contains `:set prompt " λ> "
:set prompt-cont "|λ> "
:set -XFlexibleContexts
:set -package random
:set -package matrix
:set -package arithmoi
:set -package hmatrix
:set -package vector
:set -package linear`. I'll have to do some digging to remember the answer for the latter.

Comment: Are there any files in `~/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.8.3/environments`? Perhaps you must pass `-package-env <something>` to `ghc-pkg` for it to use the same environment as ghci. (If so, that seems like a huge usability bug to me.)

Comment: @DanielWagner The only file there is `default`, which reads `clear-package-db
global-package-db
package-db ~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/package.db
package-id ghc-8.8.3
package-id bytestring-0.10.10.0`...
`package-id directory-1.3.6.0
package-id text-1.2.4.0
package-id nwsynth-0.3.0.4-aded700f` (the ...'s are a bunch more `package-id`s)

Comment: @zjs Okay. Then try my suggested `ghc-pkg` commands again, but using that environment (i.e. by adding `-package-env default` to the commands).

Comment: @DanielWagner I might have formatted it wrong, but Terminal seemed not to like the modification: while in `~/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-8.8.3/environments` I entered `ghc-pkg list random -package-env default` but got back `ghc-pkg: unrecognized option \`-p'
unrecognized option \`-a'
unrecognized option \`-c'
unrecognized option \`-k'
unrecognized option \`-a'
unrecognized option \`-g'
unrecognized option \`-e'
unrecognized option \`--env'
For usage information see 'ghc-pkg --help'.`

Comment: Ugh. Unlike ghc, apparently ghc-pkg doesn't understand environments. I should have read the documentation more carefully before suggesting it, sorry. The correct way will be something like `ghc-pkg --global --package-db ~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/package.db describe newsynth` and similar. I took this `package-db` path from the `default` environment file contents you pasted; it's possible there are other `package-db` commands in the part you omitted that should also be included. (Perhaps you are starting to see why people generally use cabal for this stuff instead of doing it manually...)

Comment: Gotcha, that worked -- the output is a bit long for a comment, so I've put it here: https://pastebin.com/TAuQJnNz. I'm not sure how to interpret the output, in particular the `depends` portion. Also, is this something that could feasibly be moved over to Cabal management?

Comment: @DanielWagner I managed to figure out how to check for `random`s, and there are indeed two versions: `random-1.1` and `random-1.2.0`. I tried hiding them using `ghc-pkg --global --package-db ~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/package.db hide random-x` and then tried running the code in GHCi, but both times got the same `No instance for...` error. Should I be hiding/exposing them in a different manner?

Comment: Presumably you should expose the version that is in `newsynth`'s dependency tree.

Comment: I tried hiding each and still got that the code does not work. Is it possible that GHCi checks for hidden/exposed packages from a different location? (If so, I don't see where else it could be finding copies of `random`...). I'll also update the main post to more accurately reflect what the issue is.